# How to average data on periods from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I'm trying to average data on specific period of time and then, averaging a date between from these result.

Having data like:

```
 value |        datetime
-------+------------------------
    15 | 2015-08-16 01:00:40+02
    22 | 2015-08-16 01:01:40+02
    16 | 2015-08-16 01:02:40+02
    19 | 2015-08-16 01:03:40+02
    21 | 2015-08-16 01:04:40+02
    18 | 2015-08-16 01:05:40+02
    29 | 2015-08-16 01:06:40+02
    16 | 2015-08-16 01:07:40+02
    16 | 2015-08-16 01:08:40+02
    15 | 2015-08-16 01:09:40+02
```

I would like to obtain something like in one query:

```
 value |        datetime
-------+------------------------
  18.6 | 2015-08-16 01:03:00+02
  18.8 | 2015-08-16 01:08:00+02
```

where value corresponding with the first 5 initial values averaged and the datetime with the middle (or average) of the 5 intial datetimes. 5 representing the interval n.

I saw some posts that put me on the track with avg, group by and averaging date format in SQL but I'm still not able to find out what to do exactly.

I'm working under PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you came up with those dates and values?

Comment: Sure, actually these data are automatically inserted from station measures.

Comment: No, the results that you're looking to get. Why do you expect to see those two specific times?

Comment: Well, that was not explained enough, by bad. From these data I would like to obtain averaged data and date every n result. For example, the couple of column value and datetime will have for each outputed lines the average of data and date every 5 initials records.

Comment: Shouldn't the average times be 02 and 07 then?

Comment: Possible, I haven't done a query on, just tried to make it on the fly :)

Comment: If you don't understand your requirements well enough to calculate the expected results for a small dataset by hand then you've got other problems.

Comment: And in what that's supposed to help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT
   to_timestamp(round(AVG(EXTRACT(epoch from datetime)))) as middleDate,
   avg(value) AS avgValue
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY
   (id) / ((SELECT Count(*) FROM myTable) / 100);
```

filled roughtly my requirements, with 100 acting on averaged intervals length (globally equals to the outputed lines).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to share more information but here is a way to do it.  Here is more information on it : [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
mysql> SELECT AVG(value), AVG(datetime)
        FROM database.table
        WHERE datetime > date1 
        AND datetime < date2;
```